# In rxjava2 Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, rx-java2

```
I have some problems when I use rxjava2 with retrofit.The following is my code:


public void sendRequest(String url, MySubscriber<NetMessage> ss, HashMap<String, String> data) {
    Flowable<NetMessage> mObservable;
    String[] paths = url.split("/");
    mObservable = myApi.getData(paths[0], paths[1], data);
    mObservable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(ss);
}
```

Here is the code I call the function

```
public void sendRequestForModifyInfo(final String field, final String value) {
    MySubscriber<NetMessage> ss = new MySubscriber<NetMessage>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(NetMessage o) {
            super.onNext(o);
            if (o != null && o.getCode() == 0) {
                JJMToast.showToast(thisActivity, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            switch (field) {
                case "nickname":
                    ((TextView) views.get(2)).setText(value);
                    break;
                case "description":
                    ((TextView) views.get(3)).setText(value);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            super.onError(t);
            JJMToast.showToast(thisActivity, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    };
    JJMApiManager.getInstance().sendRequest(HttpData.InterfaceURL.USER_MODIFY, ss, HttpData.getUserModify(RunTimeInfo.getInstance().login_token, field, value));
}
```

It is right when the length of the **value** is short,When I make the length of the **value** longer.It report the error: 
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**

**getData** is an abstract function

Comment: any ui operation in **getData**??

Comment: no ui operation  in **getData()**

Comment: Can you check the stack trace of the exception to see what method throws it?